# dependency resolution issue in gradle

Tags: gradle-plugin

i developed project in gradle using  hadoop and hive dependencies below are the dependencies of project

```
org.apache.hive:hive-common:1.2.1'
     'org.apache.hive:hive-service:1.2.1'
    'org.apache.hive:hive-metastore:1.2.1'
     'org.apache.derby:derby:10.11.1.1'
     'org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:1.2.1'
```

but i am facing below error which i am unable to resolve wonderful thing is that if i build the project using maven and added same dependencies in maven project its working fine could you please let me know problem associated with gradle
    error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not find org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:5.1.5-jhyde.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/pentaho/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm/5.1.5-jhyde/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm-5.1.5-jhyde.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/pentaho/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm/5.1.5-jhyde/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm-5.1.5-jhyde.jar
  Required by:
      :HiveUnit:unspecified > org.apache.hive:hive-service:1.2.1 > org.apache.hive:hive-exec:1.2.1 > org.apache.calcite:calcite-core:1.2.0-incubating
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the suggested hack in your build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "http://conjars.org/repo"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be aware of the security restrictions with [conjars.org](https://malcolmsparks.com/posts/library-distribution.html)

Answer (score 1):

As hack could be used

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "http://conjars.org/repo"
    }
}
```